# Как добавить файл трансформации?

Tags: c#, .net

В проекте есть `app.config`. Надо чтобы при `build`на `app.config` накатывался файл трансформации. Но с условием, что файл для трансформации существует.
Я так понимаю, что это делается в csproj проекта в `Target`. Но не пойму как задать условие и использовать трансформацию. Поможете?

Comment: Есть готовые механизмы (SlowCheetah), не хотите использовать в своём проекте? Ну или вам шашечки - то можете расковырять механизмы этого расширения и посмотреть, как оно работает. Со SlowCheetah всё в коробке - нужно только щёлкнуть rightclick'ом по app.config и выбрать пункт add transform.

Comment: А в нем можно ставить условие? Что использовать трансформацию, только в случае если этот файл есть?

Comment: Трансформации в этом расширении используются безусловные: есть две готовые трансформы (app.Debug.config и app.Release.config), каждая подключается к своей Target. Вы так и не сказали сценарий, так что не стану писать как ответ - непонятно, то вообще нужно или что-то другое.

Comment: я сделал с помощью SlowCheetah. Поставил условие `<Target Name="UseAppDebugConfig" Condition="Exists('\app.Debug.config')">` и мне этого хватило

Comment: Напишите тогда ответом и поставьте галку.

Answer (score 2):

сделал с помощью SlowCheetah. Поставил условие `<Target Name="UseAppDebugConfig" Condition="Exists('\app.Debug.config')">`